# Netapp incoming error message , HA Group Notification from NTAP01 (FCP PARTNER PATH MISCONFIGURED) ERROR

Tags: netapp

HA Group Notification from NTAP01 (FCP PARTNER PATH MISCONFIGURED) ERROR

sometimes i am getting that error on my cluster netapp storage ?  Any ideas about this ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be in misconfiguration of multipathing on hosts or switches side.
You can chek [this KB](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1004990) from NetApp. It's quite informative and detailed.

Comment: I checked all multipathing is correct . I am thinking its about i/o loads and controller sometimes can not handle and sending this message , but its not often , once in a month maybe.